# Comparing Generics that are comparable in Java

Tags: java, generics, compare, comparable

I have a Generic Binary Tree that will add objects lessThan or equalTo to the left, and objects greater than to the right. My problem is with the comparing the Generics, I know the data value will be a object-wrapped primitive or a String, so they are comparable. But, I do not know how to implement this in the code.

The code is a work in progress, I know the add methods don't add correctly yet, but I am working on that. Thanks

Here is the TreeNode:

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    //Instance Variables
    TreeNode leftChild;
    TreeNode rightChild;
    int childCount;
    int depth;
    T data;


    public TreeNode(T data, int parentDepth)
    {
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;
        childCount = 0;
        depth = parentDepth + 1;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public TreeNode(int parentDepth)
    {
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;
        childCount = 0;
        depth = parentDepth + 1;
        data = null;
    }


    public void add(T data)
    {
        if (this.data.compareTo(data) <= 0)
        {
            addLeft(data);
        } else if (this.data.compareTo(data) > 0)
        {
            addRight(data);
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR IN TREENODE.ADD");
        }
    }


    public void addLeft(T data)
    {
        leftChild = new TreeNode(data, depth);
    }

    public void addLeft()
    {
        leftChild = new TreeNode(depth);
    }


    public void addRight(T data)
    {
        rightChild = new TreeNode(data, depth);
    }

    public void addRight() {
        rightChild = new TreeNode(depth);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793082/java-comparing-generic-types) question, it is exactly the same issue as yours.

Comment: On a side note, I'm not sure if this makes a difference but I'd make your `leftChild` and `rightChild` of type **`TreeNode<T>`** instead of `TreeNode`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know the data value will be a object-wrapped primitive or a String, so they are comparable.

Then you can tell the compiler about it:

```
public class TreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

If you do that, you will get access to the `compareTo` method defined in `Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I had tried to implement Comparable<T> and that did not work, but extending did. If you could explain why, that would help me learn, but this worked for my immediate problem.

Comment: That's just a syntax thing. There is no `<T implements X>`. Only `<T extends X>` and `<T super X>` (its opposite), both of which do not make a distinction between classes and interfaces.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 1):

Your T should be implementing Comparable interface in order to compare.

```
public class TreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    //Instance Variables
    TreeNode leftChild;
    TreeNode rightChild;
    int childCount;
    int depth;
    T data;


    public TreeNode(T data, int parentDepth)
    {
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;
        childCount = 0;
        depth = parentDepth + 1;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public TreeNode(int parentDepth)
    {
        leftChild = null;
        rightChild = null;
        childCount = 0;
        depth = parentDepth + 1;
        data = null;
    }


    public void add(T data)
    {
        if (this.data.compareTo(data) <= 0)
        {
            addLeft(data);
        } else if (this.data.compareTo(data) > 0)
        {
            addRight(data);
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR IN TREENODE.ADD");
        }
    }


    public void addLeft(T data)
    {
        leftChild = new TreeNode(data, depth);
    }

    public void addLeft()
    {
        leftChild = new TreeNode(depth);
    }


    public void addRight(T data)
    {
        rightChild = new TreeNode(data, depth);
    }

    public void addRight() {
        rightChild = new TreeNode(depth);
    }
}
```

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`