# Generic code for Maximum Number

Tags: java

```
import java .util.*;
import java.io.*;
class MaxIt<T extends Number >
    {
   T x;
 public T maxi(T a,T b)
  {
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
  }
}
public class MaxGen{
     public  static void main(String[] args)
 {

    MaxIt<Integer> i=new MaxIt<Integer>();
    System.out.println("enter two integer ");
    int a,b;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    a=sc.nextInt();
    b=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a,b);

} }
```

I was reading about generic, so i have tried to make a generic program for finding maximum of two numbers but when i am compiling this it is giving me an error saying that - bad operand type for binary operator '>'.
can u tell me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: You have used local variables and not initialized them..this shouldn't compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java comparing generic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793082/java-comparing-generic-types)

Comment: You can't use `<` on a `Number` directly.  You can use it on a `Number`'s `doubleValue()` though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Comparable`, and you might make the method `static` and it could take a variable number of arguments. Something like,

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T maxi(T... vals) {
    if (vals == null || vals.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    T m = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
        if (m.compareTo(vals[i]) < 1) {
            m = vals[i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Then you need to actually call it. Something like,

```
System.out.println(maxi(a,b));
```

Comment: ok now it is working.But i could not understand two things.1.<? super T> and 2.why we cannot use '<' .

Comment: **1.** [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2970947) **2.** Because Java does **not** have [*operator overloading*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading).