# Generic permutation function element comparison gives compiler error

Tags: java, generics, permutation

I tried to create a generic `next_permutation()` function which would do the same thing as the C++ `next_permutation()` function. The compiler says:

> bad operand types for binary operator '>' and '<',

at the following lines:

- `if (data.get(last) < data.get(last + 1))`
- `if (if data.get(i) > data.get(last))`

How do I resolve this?

```
public static <T> boolean findNextPermutation(List<T> data) 
{ 


    if (data.size() <= 1) 
        return false; 

    int last = data.size() - 2; 

    while (last >= 0) { 
        if (data.get(last) < data.get(last + 1)) { 
            break; 
        } 
        last--; 
    } 

    if (last < 0) 
        return false; 

    int nextGreater = data.size() - 1; 

    for (int i = data.size() - 1; i > last; i--) { 
        if (data.get(i) > data.get(last)) { 
            nextGreater = i; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 

    data = swap(data, nextGreater, last); 

    data = reverse(data, last + 1, data.size() - 1); 

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20793082/java-comparing-generic-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` can be anything. It might be of type `Integer` or of type `String`. An `Integer` can be unboxed to an `int` and compared with `<` or `>`, but a `String` cannot.

You need to narrow down what `T` can be. One way would be to force `T` to implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). You can then make use of the [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean findNextPermutation(List<T> data) {

  if (data.size() <= 1)
    return false;

  int last = data.size() - 2;

  while (last >= 0) {
    if (data.get(last).compareTo(data.get(last + 1)) < 0) {
      break;
    }
    last--;
  }

  if (last < 0)
    return false;

  int nextGreater = data.size() - 1;

  for (int i = data.size() - 1; i > last; i--) {
    if (data.get(i).compareTo(data.get(last)) > 0) {
      nextGreater = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  data = swap(data, nextGreater, last);

  data = reverse(data, last + 1, data.size() - 1);

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `T` does not or can not implement `Comparable` as proposed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61006248/3992939) answer you can supply a `Comparator<T>` and use it:

```
public static <T> boolean findNextPermutation(List<T> data, Comparator<T> comperator) {

      if (data.size() <= 1)  return false;

      int last = data.size() - 2;

      while (last >= 0) {
        if (comperator.compare(data.get(last),data.get(last + 1)) < 0 ){
          break;
        }
        last--;
      }

      if (last < 0) return false;

      int nextGreater = data.size() - 1;

      for (int i = data.size() - 1; i > last; i--) {
        if (comperator.compare(data.get(i), data.get(last)) > 0) {
          nextGreater = i;
          break;
        }
      }

      data = swap(data, nextGreater, last);
      data = reverse(data, last + 1, data.size() - 1);

      return true;
}
```

Side note: you can make a null friendly cooperator. For example:
 
`Comparator<T> nullSafeComperator = Comparator.nullsFirst(comperator);`